# Awk issue, duplicate lines in multiple files at once.

Tags: linux, bash, awk, duplicates, printf

I've an issue with formatting output on the below.

I've duplicate lines in many files SHORT_LIST.a SHORT_LIST.b SHORT_LIST.c, but there can be many, many more.

the line "test1" exists in all three files, as does the string "sample".

The line "test" exists in two files, but exists more than once in one of the files, I'd like to have it output this just once per file name.

```
function check_duplicates {

 awk 'END {
   for (R in rec) {
   #split out the SHORT_LIST files
    n = split(rec[R], t, "/SHORT_LIST")
    #printf n dup[n]
    count = 0
if  ( n > 2 )
 dup[n] = dup[n] ? dup[n] RS sprintf( R, rec[R]) :
   sprintf("\t%-20s %s ", R, rec[R]);
}
for (D in dup) {
  ((count++))
   printf "%s\n \n", d
   printf count " ). Duplicate record(s) found in the following files: " dup[D]
     }
   }
{
   # build an array named rec (short for record), indexed by
   # the content of the current record ($0), concatenating
   # the filenames separated by / as values
   rec[$0] = rec[$0] ? rec[$0] "\n \t" FILENAME : FILENAME
   }' $SITEFILES

  }

check_duplicates
```

**Current output below :**

Duplicate records found in the following files:

1 ). Duplicate record(s) found in the following files:  test1
    SHORT_LIST.a
    SHORT_LIST.b
    SHORT_LIST.c
sample

2 ). Duplicate record(s) found in the following files:  test
    SHORT_LIST.c
    SHORT_LIST.b
    SHORT_LIST.b
    SHORT_LIST.b

3 ). Duplicate record(s) found in the following files:  /path/to/file
    SHORT_LIST.a
    SHORT_LIST.c
testa

**Desired Output below :**

Duplicate records found in the following files:

1 ). Duplicate record(s) found in the following files:  test1
    SHORT_LIST.a
    SHORT_LIST.b
    SHORT_LIST.c

2 ). Duplicate record(s) found in the following files:  sample
    SHORT_LIST.a
    SHORT_LIST.b
    SHORT_LIST.c

3 ). Duplicate record(s) found in the following files:  test
    SHORT_LIST.c
    SHORT_LIST.b

4 ). Duplicate record(s) found in the following files:  /path/to/file
    SHORT_LIST.a
    SHORT_LIST.c

5 ). Duplicate record(s) found in the following files:  testa
    SHORT_LIST.a
    SHORT_LIST.c

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm having trouble with this level of AWK.

Comment: I'm not sure how that wold help though? I need to list the duplicate, and each file it's in.

Comment: Taking down my original comment. Maybe something like `sort -o file.srt file ; sort file2.srt file2 ; comm -12 file.srt file2.srt >file1_2.comm; awk '{print "Dupes :"$0}' file1_2.comm` would allow you to use standard tools, rather than "reinvent the wheel" ;-) . You'll have to take the time to read about `comm` to determine if you can make it's output work for you. Good luck.

Comment: The thing is, I'm passing in predetermined files via $SITEFILES, they are passed into a larger script at the start, and can be arranged by name, date, size, etc. so I can't just give it some file names, because at times i'll have one file, at others I could have 5000, it depends on what's going through the earlier processing.

Comment: @ben, posting some sample files would make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split it out by multiple files, and within the same file, I also put stuff in to allow for comments to be ignored, you could do this with white space too, etc.

Thanks so much to @karakfa your answer was amazing, thanks.

```
function check_duplicates {
 #Check multiple files for duplicates.   
  awk '
   FNR==1{files[FILENAME]}
          {if((FILENAME, $0) in a) dupsInFile[FILENAME]
           else
             {a[FILENAME, $0]
              dups[$0] = $0 in dups ? (dups[$0] RS FILENAME) : FILENAME
              count[$0]++}}
              #ignore comment lines
               {if ($0 ~ /#/) {
                   delete dups[$0]
                }}
  #Print duplicates in more than one file
          END{for(k in dups)
             {if(count[k] > 1)
               {print ("\n\n\tDuplicate line found: " k) "\n\tIn the following file(s)"
                 print dups[k] }}
          printf "\n";


       }' $SITEFILES
 #Check single files for duplicates.    
 awk '
 NR {
     b[$0]++
    }
    #ignore comment lines
        $0 in b {
           if ($0 ~ /#/) {
           delete b[$0]
                         }
                      if (b[$0]>1) {
                      print ("\n\n\tDuplicate line found: "$0) "\n\tIn the following file"
                      print FILENAME
                      delete b[$0]
                      }
    }' $SITEFILES


  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You can follow this template and fix the output format as desired

$ awk -f dups.awk fa fb fc

dups for : /path/to/file in files
fa fc
dups for : test in files
fa fb fc
dups for : sample in files
fa fb fc
no dups in
fc

$ cat dups.awk

  FNR==1{files[FILENAME]}
        {if((FILENAME, $0) in a) dupsInFile[FILENAME]
         else
           {a[FILENAME, $0]
            dups[$0] = $0 in dups ? (dups[$0] FS FILENAME) : FILENAME
            count[$0]++}}
     END{for(k in dups)
           {if(count[k] > 1)
              {print ("dups for : " k) " in files"
               print dups[k]}}
        for(f in dupsInFile) delete files[f];
        print "no dups in";
        for(f in files) printf "%s", f FS;
        printf "\n";
     }
```

where

```
$ head f{a,b,c}
==> fa <==
test
test
test1
sample
/path/to/file

==> fb <==
test
test
sample

==> fc <==
test
sample
/path/to/file
```

ps. always provide sample input.

Comment: Woah thanks, this is perfect! - em, any idea how I can find dupes in the same file? or how I could add a newline between the file names? i.e. "fa" \n "fb" \n "fc"

Comment: i.e. fb has test in there twice, for each line in these files a job is kicked off, so it's important to catch duplicates in each file too. if that makes any sense?

Comment: My understanding from your "The line "test" exists...output just once per file name." statement is you don't want to report duplicates within a file.

Comment: OH, sorry, lost in translation then, I want to A ) report duplicates in multiple files, and B) report duplicates within each single file. I hope this makes sense.   Also, just out of curiosity, the array with the file names in it, dups[k] , any idea how I can print these elements on a line each?

Comment: your format is single line: for separate lines per filename: replace 'FS` with 'RS'.  For duplicates in the same file, you can work on the section with dupsInFile array which keeps the file names where duplicates exist.  store the entries in another array indexed by file name, similar to dups array.

Comment: Thanks, if I get it complete I'll post the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
 awk '{print FILENAME "\t" $0}' $SITEFILES \
 | sort \
 | uniq -c -f1 \
 | awk "{if ($1 + .0 != 1) print $0}'
```

will get you started

*Without small sample data sets, it's not practical to do more on this.*

IHTH